# Running Wireguard Client on Docker / WSL

Tags: windows, networking, vpn, docker, wireguard

Can I run wireguard on docker / WSL2 and share that wireguard connection to the Windows 10 that I am running it on ? I want the docker container / WSL2 to act as a WIreguard client Application for windows. How can I do this ?

https://download.wireguard.com/windows-client/wireguard-installer.exe

Once I get the networking work, I plan make my own UI to control it.

***Explanation / Edit :***                                                        I am trying to work around the Wireguard Windows Client Application through this.                                                                                 Config for WSL2 :                                                                  [ifconfig](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5lSpd.jpg)
[wireguard WSL linux](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uN7nB.jpg)
[ping](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X5RPy.jpg)

Comment: The Windows Wireguard client obviously cannot run on WSL. WSL2 is a full Linux kernel.  So there shouldn't be any reason you cannot run a linux version of Wireguad.

Comment: I am able to run the wireguard linux on WSL using apt packages, wireguard, wireguard-tools. I can connect to the server as well. But the problem is that I can only ping the server using the wg0 interface on WSL, ping -I wg0 <IP address on Server Side>.                                                        
However, if I run the wireguard on windows, I can navigate to certain webpages hosted on server side IP addresses using browser. I want to share that wireguard  connection to the windows as well. Like routing all the traffic through the wg0 interface ?